# sqlite-pcl vs sqlite-net xamarin component

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, android-sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have installed [sqlite-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/), but there is also component for Xamarin [sqlite-net](https://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net).

What is the main difference between those references? And which of them has better performance?

As I know pcl doesn't support relationships (foreign key), but sqlite-net does. So I use `[Indexed]` attribute for better performance, does it make seance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both based on the same [Sqlite.Net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library but the [PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) project is a fork which tries to improve on the previous project:

> This is a fork of the original sqlite-net library
>   (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), which aims to improve the
>   code quality by using modern technologies such as PCL (portable class
>   library).
>
> The project will avoid the use of #if-based conditional code and use
>   platform-specific code injection instead.
>
> I welcome pull requests, but keep in mind that this library is in
>   heavy use and all changes must be:
>
> Backwards-compatible (don't change database defaults). Well tested
>   (please add unit tests).

Both **don't** support foreign keys.
Performance-wise the PCL project supposed to be better, but that is untested as far as I know.